# issue when building NPanday Building a web application

Tags: asp.net, .net, apache, maven

[UPDATE]
the clean goal runs smoothely all over the projects of the solution, the problem now while running the **compile** goal, below the error message:

[INFO] Total time: 19.427s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Jun 29 11:46:28 WEST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/306M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.npanday.plugins:maven-aspx-plugin:1.4.0-incubating:compile (default-compile) on project B3GMcsInterface: NPANDAY-900-006: Unable to Compile: Language = ASP, Vendor = null, ArtifactType = asp, Source Directory = C:\Users\CASA-WS001\Desktop\Gateway\ProjectName: NPANDAY-040-001: Could not execute: Command =  cmd.exe /X /C "aspnet_compiler -v " /MyArtifactId" -p C:\Users\CASA-W~1\AppData\Local\Temp\maven-aspx-plugin-3088047295012139775\src -u -f C:\Users\CASA-W~1\AppData\Local\Temp\maven-aspx-plugin-3088047295012139775\dest -nologo -fixednames", Result = 1 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn  -rf :B3GMcsInterface
NPanday Execution Failed!, with exit code: 1

[END OF UPDATE]





i'm trying to make the build of simple web application using NPanday, i am using the incubating 1.4.0 plugin for VS2010, i have successfully built C# Console or Libraries Projects using maven, but when i tried to clean a web application i encounter this kind of error
Below is the error output.

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.628s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Jun 26 17:53:56 WET 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/16M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Error resolving version for plugin 'npanday.plugin:maven-aspx-plugin' from the
 repositories [local (C:\Users\user1.m2\repository), central 
(http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]: Plugin not found in any plugin repository -> [Help1]
[ERROR]
 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] 
http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginVersionResolutionException

any help is appreciated.
Thank You.

Comment: Sorry this output is for the Clean goal not Compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the "npanday.plugin" in "npanday.plugin:maven-aspx-plugin"... It must be wrongly stated in one of the life cycles.

Things have moved to "org.apache.npanday.plugins": http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22maven-aspx-plugin%22

Try using 1.5.0-SNAPSHOT from the following repository. It contains a mass of improvements! I'm using it in production.

```
<pluginRepositories>
  <pluginRepository>
    <releases>
      <enabled>false</enabled>
    </releases>
    <id>npanday.snapshots</id>
    <name>NPanday Snapshot Repository</name>
    <url>http://vmbuild.apache.org/archiva/repository/npanday-snapshots</url>
  </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: thank you it's working now the clean|compil|install|test maven goals if i run them from vs2010 or cmd.exe, i have changed the npanday-setting.xml generated by the npanday plugin the problem that i couldn't find some .net utility for some .net framework.now the prolem is i cannot run comile or install goals from jenkins,if you have any idea this will be much better.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use a repository manager and define a supplemental repository which contains the given dependencies / plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Error is related plugins order in pom.xml:

If maven-compile-plugin is before maven-aspx-plugin, you get the error.

But if the order is maven-aspx-plugin and then maven-compile-plugin, mvn compile works

Snip of the correct pom.xml:

```
....
       <plugins>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.npanday.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-aspx-plugin</artifactId>
              <extensions>true</extensions>
              <configuration>
                <frameworkVersion>4.0</frameworkVersion>
              </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.npanday.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-compile-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>1.4.0-incubating</version>
              <extensions>true</extensions>
....
```